# Incremental encoder with memory

Tags: applied-mechanics, robotics, wheels

I'm working on a robotics project. In this project we need to control the angle position of the wheels. We are going to use an incremental encoder (we didn't find an absolute encoder that was able to to fit into the structure of the system). My question is, is there a method that we can use to store the position of the encoder in case of a power shutdown? I was thinking about ways to save the last position in a non volatile memory (internal microcontroller memory or a sd carf, for example).

Comment: Often, such devices will reset/"home" their position instead of remembering it. What if someone pushes the wheel while the power is off? The memory won't be correct. Instead, you could slowly move the wheel in one direction, until it goes as far as it can go, and then you use a switch to detect that, and then you know where the wheel is.

Comment: Your request doesn't make sense if you think about it. How does memory help when it can be rotated while powered down?

Comment: @user253751 thanks for your answer. Yes, I think that using a switch is the best and most robust solution that we have right now.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to clarify "angle position of the wheels"? Do you mean the rotational angle or the steering angle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if someone pushes the wheel while the power is off? The memory won't be correct.

A typical solution to this problem is to use a "home switch". When the robot starts up, it can rotate the wheel in one direction until it bumps into a switch which you have installed in a certain position. Then, the software knows the wheel position, and can track it from then on.

You indicated in the comments that this solution works for you.